# How to Signature with RSA in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to Use  simple_rsa  in Signature OR verify?

```
simple_rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing install Simple RSA

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  simple_rsa: ^0.0.5
```

Import it
Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:simple_rsa/simple_rsa.dart';
```

Try this to Sign :

```
final publicKey = '...';
final privateKey = '...';
String plainText = 'something';

final Signture = await signString(plainText, PrivateKey);
```

Try this to Verify :

```
final Verified = await verifiedString(plainText, Signture , publicKey);
```